# Python how can I add metadata to a LimaCharlie FP rule?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fpgrowth

I am using [LimaCharlie Python](https://github.com/refractionPOINT/python-limacharlie) in order to push rules to my LimaCharlie organization.

I have the following false positive rule that contains ´data´ with the rule and some ´metadata´ with for example tags.

**fp_rule.yml:**

```
---
data:
  op: and
  rules:
    - op: is
      path: cat
      value: Command Detected

    - op: or
      rules:

        - op: ends with
          path: detect/event/PARENT/FILE_PATH
          value: "\\A\\B\\C\\D.exe"
          case sensitive: false

metadata:
  author: someone@mycompany.com
  tlp: amber
  title: Command Detected
  description: Legitimate Command Detected
  source:
  tags:
  state: production
  version: 1.0.0
```

I can easily add a new false positive rule to LimaCharlie, however how can I add metadata?

**This is my script deploy_fp_rule_test.py:**

```
import os

import limacharlie
import yaml


def deploy_fp_rule_test():
    # Log into LimaCharlie
    limacharlie_organization_id = os.environ['limacharlie_organization_id']
    limacharlie_signatures_api_key = os.environ['limacharlie_signatures_api_key']
    manager = limacharlie.Manager(oid=limacharlie_organization_id, secret_api_key=limacharlie_signatures_api_key)


    # Read rule
    with open(f"fp_rule.yml", mode='r',
              encoding="utf8") as stream:
        try:
            fp_rule = yaml.safe_load(stream)
        except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
            print(exc)

    # Map rule parts
    fp_rule_data = fp_rule['data']
    fp_rule_metadata = fp_rule['metadata']

    # Add to LimaCharlie
    result = manager.add_fp(name="Command Detected", rule=fp_rule_data, isReplace=True)
    print(f"{result}")

# - Main start ----------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    deploy_fp_rule_test()
```